# Empty Object Explorer When Opening a H2 embedded database(.mv.db file) in DbVisualizer

Tags: mysql, database, h2, dbvisualizer, h2db

EDIT: Please ignore the Database Type "MySQL". I have it set to H2 currently, I was just playing around with settings at the time of the screengrabs in an attempt to see if I could pinpoint what was going wrong.

My friend came to me tonight with an "Opportunity".  He had a college student code a front end application to insert, update, delete, and view data on a local drive for a small company that he runs. The application broke when he updated windows, and now he needs to retrieve the data.  He sent me the .mv.db file, so I did some digging and found that DbVisualizer could allow me to atleast use a simple MySQL query to pull his data out into an excel spreadsheet.  According to him, there are only about 300 records in the database.

When I connect to the embedded H2 database, it opens up two empty databases.

[image]

[image]

Let me know if anybody knows what to do here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Luckily my database was small as well so I could use [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/squirrel-sql/?source=typ_redirect) to open the database. It is not easy to get used to the user interface but it does a really good job.

- If you want to export your data you probably want to change the settings (File -> Global Preferences, Tab SQL Script). I unticked the box 'Qualify .. with schema' to get valid SQL.
- Also the date format is not standard conform. I used a text editor to get executable SQL.